# Find out what js file was loaded, but not used

Tags: javascript, developer-tools

Is there a way to know what js files was loaded in html, but not used? Let's say I load on a HTML page jQuery, jQuery Tabs, jQuery DatePicker libs, but on that page I use none o them, except jQuery. Is there  a way to find out what js files where used ( executed )?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer - No.

### Long answer:

Since the files are referenced in the page itself, all scripts would be loaded, executed and it's code(global variables and functions - `$` for example) exposed.

The only way to check if a certain part of a script is executed, is to observe the actors or -in other words- the calling code and the called code.

For example:

```
function callingFunction() {
  console.log('I will call this code!');
  calledFunction();
}

function calledFunction() {
  /// <summary>
  /// Lets say this function is added in a external file
  /// </summary>

  console.log('My code was called!');
}
```

### onDemand scriptloading

A good aproach would be to load your libraries only when needed. jQuery's [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) is doing a great job here. If you reference your libraries like this, you can check the currently loaded ones via the network panel.

### Update

Chrome 59 now supports Code coverage which does something similar. 
Check it out
https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/devtools-release-notes#coverage

Comment: Is there a way to hook all javascript functions and then just add the console.log from the callback?

Comment: @RohnAdams not as far as I know - but why would you do that?

Comment: I have taken over a project and on every .html page there is a huge list of JS scripts being included. I feel as though many of them don't need to be included on every page, only on pages requiring the functionality of whatever script. I was hoping to quickly identify which were not needed by the page so I could keep them from being needlessly included. If i could hook ALL JS function calls, this seemed like a good way of determining which functions are called on what pages.

Comment: well the newest version of chrome has a lot of useful tools to do exactly that. the new code coverage check should give you somewhat of information. also you could simply disable the files via click and check if the functionality ist still there.

Comment: Awesome, I was unaware of this code coverage tool. It looks as if it will do exactly what I want. Thanks.

Comment: @RohnAdams you are welcome - thats why I updated my answer yesterday ;)

Answer (score 0):

No not really. When you include all files, all javascript code in that file is loaded. If you want to load the js file at the moment you use a function in it, you can check if the plugin is available. If it isn't available then include the file.

E.g.:

```
if(jQuery().datepicker) {
     //Include datepicker here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No cause when you include any js into your page it gets loaded,
though you can check what is getting run when you interact with things using thne chrome event listeners tab.
[image]

That's the closest you are gonna get

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way to do what you want. If the purpose is to do lazy loading, prefer use a library like [require](http://requirejs.org/)